# Some question of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}(V)$ be a $r+1$ dimensional projective space where $V$ is a vector space.
I don't understand tensor product $V\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}$... and why this is trivial bundle....
help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a ringed space defined over a commutative ring $k$, $M$ an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module and let $V$ be a module over $k$. Then $V \otimes_k M$ is defined to be the $\mathcal{O}_X$-module which is associated to the presheaf $U \mapsto V \otimes_k \Gamma(U,M)$. One verifies that this satisfies the usual adjunction $\hom(V \otimes_k M,N) \cong \hom(V,\hom(M,N))$ (in other words, $\mathsf{Mod}(X)$ is *tensored* over $\mathsf{Mod}(k)$). If $V$ is a free module, say $V=k^{\oplus I}$, then $V \otimes_k M = M^{\oplus I}$ is a direct sum of copies of $M$. In particular, if $M = \mathcal{O}_X$, this is a free module aka trivial bundle.